# How do I draw something when the mouse is clicked?

Tags: xna

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
public void buttonsClicked()
{
    if (lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released 
    && currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        buttonWasClicked();
    }
 }

public void buttonWasClicked()
{
    MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
    spriteBatch.Draw(smallPotTexture, pos, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
 }
```

I want this to draw `smallPotTexture` where I click. However, the above code doesn't work. What's the proper way to do this?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I use `spriteBatch.Begin`, maybe I'm not allowed to do that this way?

Comment: I edited your question to be more on topic for the site. Note the changes I've made and attempt to ask your future questions in the same manner. Make the title relevant, something searchable. "What's wrong with this code" is not what you really wanted to know (and it's not useful in a search), you wanted to know how to draw something when the mouse is clicked. Only post the bare minimum code, we don't need irrelevant code cluttering up the question.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I use
>   spriteBatch.Begin, maybe I'm not allowed to do that this way?

You'd be correct. The `spriteBatch` should only be used from within a `Draw` method, and I'm guessing that `buttonWasClicked` is called from an `Update()` method?

You'll need to store some information in the `buttonWasClicked` method that can later be used in the `Draw()` method.

Note that infinite loops and sleeps should not be used in XNA. XNA (and most other game frameworks) uses a Game Loop which will call [`Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.update.aspx) followed by [`Draw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.draw.aspx) once per frame, over and over again. This gives a chance for everything to update and everything to draw. I would also avoid threads unless you really know what you're doing.

Ralph has given you the codez.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to draw your smallPotTexture in the 
protected override void Draw. So the best for you to do is.

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        if (lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            pos = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(smallPotTexture, pos, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

pos will be declared as a Vector2D above in the Game class

Comment: Says "The name 'pos' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @EliasFinoli Please don't just copy/paste. Look at how the code is being used and implement it for your code. You're coming here to learn, not to have people write code for you.

Comment: Thats why i told you to declare your Vector2 pos above in the Game class